# EF4.3 Model mapping to 2 db tables

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to map a model which has items from two different db tables. I have two tables (aspnet_Users && aspnet_Membership). I want to make a model that contains fields from both.  My problem is setting that up.

It seems I need to add to my "OnModelCreating" override in my DbContext, but can't figure out what needs to go there.

Here are my models:

```
 [Table("aspnet_Users")]
 public class ApplicationUser : Base, IApplicationUser
 {
        [Key]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser_Details UserDetails { get; set;}
 }

 [Table("aspnet_Membership")]
 public class ApplicationUser_Details : Base
 {
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm trying to follow the guid on Scott Gu's website (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx -- Section 3), but I can't get it to work if EF4.3.

It seems simple enough what I'm trying to do, but for some reason struggling to find good docs on how to implement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map to existing membership tables (if I understood well what you want), you could do something like this...
(note: I'm sort of disregarding the 'Base' class as I don't see the purpose for that, you can have a base class but it complicates things a bit, so that's not 'covered'. Also not sure what you meant by 'that contains fields from both', this maps 2 tables to 2 classes, as you laid out)

```
[Table("aspnet_Users")]
public class ApplicationUser // : Base, IApplicationUser
{
    //[Key]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser_Details UserDetails { get; set; }
}

[Table("aspnet_Membership")]
public class ApplicationUser_Details // : Base
{
    //[Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

...and in your `OnModelCreating()`...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId });

//modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
//    .Property(x => x.UserId)
//    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser_Details>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId });

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser_Details>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.User)
    .WithRequiredDependent(i => i.UserDetails);
```

...that should create the right relationship (1 to 1) with FK being the PK as well (on details).

Still, if you'd just like to use membership tables in MVC or similar - this might be easier...
http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/

hope this helps,

Comment: If I implement your suggestion, when go to look at User.UserDetails, UserDetails is always null. If I add a virtual to the ApplicationUser_Details UserDetails {get;set;} method, then there's a value but I get a circular reference error: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ApplicationUser_32EAFB8C43CC9C93658E494EE6FDC9BB8192076E7322E6F7F281EE638A9FC617'.

Comment: My problem with the circular reference was solved here: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-01-25/resolving-circular-references-when-binding-the-mvc-grid.aspx

Comment: Also to note, I did have to add virtual to the solution above.

Comment: @SteveSloka problem with having 'null' you can resolve by making a LINQ query with '.Include(x=>x.UserDetails)' (or just use "UserDetails"). Circular reference is an issue with the FK ID-s 'related' to the navigation properties - i.e. the 'UserId' in your case - if you make virtual they need to be Nullable<> (with ? except for strings), which in your case I don't think you can do with a PK id. What I made is a 'required-to-required' 1-to-1. In your case I think you could just try experiment with .WithOptionalDependent. This can be worked out nicely w/o workarounds. Try those few, let me know.

Comment: thanks! I found the answer previously if you check out the blog post from telerik, it was a Javascript JSON parsing issue. I ended up creating a new ViewModel as mentioned in the article, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably shouldn't be accessing the asp.net tables directly. Use the built in providers if you can.

Secondly, I've found it much simpler in the long run to keep your entities exactly the same as your table structure. If you need to represent data differently in your application, create an application specific model. You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to help with mapping from entities to models.

> **What is AutoMapper?**
>
> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively
>   complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to
>   another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so
>   why not invent a tool to do it for us?
>
> **How do I get started?**
>
> Check out the [getting started guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started). When you're done there, the [wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)
>   goes in to the nitty-gritty details. Finally, check out the [dnrTV episode](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=155) for a full walkthrough.

Comment: I'm just playing around with some tables, and using the user tables in asp.net is a simple example.  

How do I use the AutoMapper? I understand that if my model is exactly the same as my Db it's easier, but that's my question, what if it's not? It seems it's been solved, but not sure how in the newer versions of EF to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any foreign entity mapping yourself in EF 4.3. Just make sure, that both sides of the connected entities have a corresponding reference to each other. Eq. Category entity has a property of collection of Food entities and every food entity has a property of a single Category. Also there's no need to specify table names.
After you've set up the relationships based on the Category - Food example don't forget, that you also need to handle relationships from both sides on actions such as Add and Delete.

Comment: The table names are because my models do not match my tables (so I need to tell EF how to read the db). I've been trying to run, I'm getting errors now without any mappings: {"Invalid column name 'ApplicationUser_Details_UserId'."}